# Verifying the installed dot net framework edition

Tags: .net

Many articles answer for how to identify the dot net framework version. But I need to know how to identify the edition installed (32/64 bit). Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx